# Is there a way to check if a record will be selected out by a certain select statement before inserting it to the database?

Tags: sql, oracle

In our application, we have the requirements that we need to prevent users from inserting records to the database that doesn't meet the criteria. The criteria is the where clause of a select statement, which is defined by some admin user. Here is an example, there is a table called 'Book' and an admin user has defined a criteria as "pages<=200 OR type='Children's book'". With that criteria defined, books that have pages more than 200 and the type is not "Children's book" are not allowed to be inserted into database.

```
Table: Book (id, name, author, pages， type)

Criteria: "pages<=200 OR type='Children's book'"
```

The criteria could be more complex but will follow the oracle sql syntax. One option I can think of is that insert the record first and then check if it can be selected out by the criteria, if not, then we delete if from the database, but I think there should be a neater way to do this job. It would be great if it can be done by a single sql statement.

Does anyone has a better way to do this job? Any answers would be appreciated.

**Update:**

Thank you for the answers, I think I should provide more details.

The users in question are application users, including the 'admin user', it's not a dba. The criteria can be changed quite often and it's possible we have different criteria on same table for different user groups. So hopefully, the check can be done in the application side. We are using django which has its own ORM, but I think I should first find a way to do it by using sql statements, which will concatenate the criteria at some point. Ideally, we could append the 'where clause' constraints to a insert statement so that it will insert the record into database if the values meet those constrains and otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Is the "admin user" the DBA, and are they setting these restrictions once and just once? If so, you might be looking for a `CHECK` constraint.

Comment: No, the 'admin user' is under application context, and these restrictions can be changed quite often. Plus, the criteria on the same table could be different for different user groups (also in application context). I think I should put more details in the question.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid appending the "where clause" constraints on the insert statement.  You want to move such security inside of the database.  As I mentioned below, if you can use "check option" views along with a few sys_contexts this places the burden on the DBA and removes it from the developers.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I think you are right. This kind of work is not supposed to be done at application side. Unfortunately we have a standard edition of Oracle, so VPD is not the way to go. I'm afraid we need to find other way to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

If the criteria is like in your example you should put some [check constraints](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php)

```
Alter table book add CONSTRAINT check_type CHECK (type = 'Children''s book');
Alter table book add CONSTRAINT check_pages CHECK (pages >=200);
```

Answer (score 1):

One really great way of doing this is to use a view "with check option" (and possibly a sys_context).

For example,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test (id, col_1) AS
SELECT id,  col_1 
  FROM some_table
 WHERE col1  = SYS_CONTEXT ('CTX', 'XYZ')
  WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Then grant insert permission on the view and revoke insert permission on the table.  Have the user insert into the view.

The "with check option" makes sure that all rows inserted into the view pass the "where clause".

This can also be a great way to handle row level security, (like virtual private database) in Oracle Standard Edition.

You can create 2 oracle schemas, one who owns the tables and views, and one schema who will select/insert/delete from the views (and has no permission to do anything to the tables).

Set the sys_context when the user logs in and bam.... you have perfect row level security.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle this if you have Enterprise Edition is to setup Oracle Virtual Private Database:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/index-088277.html